# eZ Platform : The route "{0}" does not exist

Tags: ezplatform

We have a ezplatform published that have been OK until recently we cleaned the symfony cache. Looks like it is not retrieving data for the route "_ezpublishLocation". In our devs enviroment those routes are filled with an array of items like ,

```
ez_content_create_no_draft:
ez_content_draft_create:
ezplatform.asset.upload_image:
....
```

The admin backend show the error "The route "_ezpublishLocation" does not exist.", when try to fill the content structure tree (the data for the tree is loaded sucessfully) in /content/location url.

Havent found any error in the logs.

Have any one some clue about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was with the permissions of the cache directory.
Deleting the cache directory loses the permissions created in the installation.

Directories and files must have the following permissions

```
   $ sudo find {app/{cache,logs},web} -type d | xargs sudo chmod -R 775
   $ sudo find {app/{cache,logs},web} -type f | xargs sudo chmod -R 664
```